# JavaScript: textarea not showing output

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a Leetspeak converter program, but the second `textarea` does not show any output. Here is my rudimentary code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1>Leetspeak Converter</h1>

    <script language="JavaScript">
    function convert(){
      var x = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
      var result='';
      for (var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (x.charAt(i)=='A'){
          result = result + '4';
        }
      }
      document.getElementById('resultTextarea').value = result ;
    }
    </script>

    <div class="input">
    <textarea id = "myTextArea" rows = "6" cols = "80">
    </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="push">
    <button onclick="convert">Convert</button>
    </div>

    <div class="result">
    <textarea id = "resultTextArea" rows = "6" cols = "80">
    </textarea>
    </div>
```

It does not produce any output at all. I have tried using `console.log()`, but it shows no output.
I have also used a debugger, but no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax errors, in 2 parts, so change this

```
<button onclick="convert">Convert</button> // this does not represent a method
```

with this

```
<button onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
```

and in addition, this

```
document.getElementById('resultTextarea').value = result ; // a small typo in id
```

with this

```
document.getElementById('resultTextArea').value = result ;
```

```js
function convert(){
      var x = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
      var result=0;
      for (var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (x.charAt(i)=='A'){
          result = result + 4;
        }
      }
      document.getElementById('resultTextArea').value = result ;
    }
```

```html
<div class="input">
    <textarea id = "myTextArea" rows = "6" cols = "80">
    </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="push">
    <button onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
    </div>

    <div class="result">
    <textarea id = "resultTextArea" rows = "6" cols = "80">
    </textarea>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Can you point out what errors I made, so I can avoid them in the future. I am new.

Comment: @toyotasupra minor issues that could happen if you work late and your eyes are tired :)

Comment: Yes, I am only 13 but code like hell, all the time, so I have been in that situation tons of times.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in:

```
<button onclick="convert">Convert</button>
```

Fixed this as:

```
<button onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1>Leetspeak Converter</h1>

    <script language="JavaScript">
    function convert(){
      var x = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;

      var result='';


      for (var i = 0,len = x.length ; i < len; i++) {
        if (x.charAt(i)=='A'){
          result = result + '4';
        }
      }

      document.getElementById('resultTextArea').value = result ;
    }
    </script>

    <div class="input">
    <textarea id = "myTextArea" rows = "6" cols = "80">
    </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="push">
    <button onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
    </div>

    <div class="result">
    <textarea id = "resultTextArea" rows = "6" cols = "80">
    </textarea>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```